# How do I get rid of the notifications for review?

Tags: support, user-interface, notifications, top-bar

The new stackexchange bar on top of the page shows notifications when new posts are available review for "Suggested edits". This is pretty annoying to see every now and then. Is there a way I can disable this notification?

Please see the screenshot(the highlighted part) for the notification I am querying about.

[image: notification for review]

Comment: Nope. No way you can remove it without a custom userscript. Why do you find it annoying?

Comment: I usually like to keep all notifications cleared(read and reviewed, if required). Getting a new notification every now and then is tiresome :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Firefox, then, using a plain text editor (create and) edit `~/.mozilla/Your_unique_profile/firefox/chrome/userContent.css` to have this:

```
@namespace html url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain(askubuntu.com) { 
SPAN.hotbg.unread-count { display: none !important }
}
```

This works on the main site.

---

To do the same in Google Chrome, you can try adding

```
SPAN.hotbg.unread-count { display: none !important }
```

to `Custom.css` which should located in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets`. If you have more than one profile, you need to specify a particular in place of `Default`.

This is not a "clean" approach because it isn't site-specific. If other sites also use `SPAN.hotbg.unread-count`, whatever that code displays in those sites will be hidden as well.

One way to get site-specific styles in Google Chrome is to use the [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe).

Comment: Do you not like the new notification either?

Comment: It doesn't bother me at all, but I like to learn about css which is how I viewed the question.

Comment: Thanks, @vasa1! I had to create `chrome/userContent.css` in  `.mozilla/firefox/ljhh82wn.default/`. I believe the path needs to be corrected in your answer too, nor sure though. Referred to this for locating the file: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_Configuration_Files#Locate_your_profile_folder. I am using Firefox 26.0